# Restrict Orientation change in Javascript

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, screen-orientation, phonegap-cli

I am building hybrid mobile application. I need to restrict orientation to portrait mode for specific screen alone. The entire page is a single html. Is it possible to set portrait or landscape specific to div. I would like to know if there is possibility to handle such case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`cordova-plugin-screen-orientation`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation) to change (or lock/unlock) the app orientation programmatically:

```
// set to either landscape
screen.lockOrientation('landscape');

// allow user rotate
screen.unlockOrientation();

// access current orientation
console.log('Orientation is ' + screen.orientation);
```